# Anyone have a generator for EF Code First seed statements?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, seed

I am converting an application to use the code first approach. My tables have hundreds of records and I do not want to write the seed statements by hand. Has anyone written a T4 template that will generate the statements that go into the DbContext seed method? The tables need to be seeded so that the foreign key tables are populated after the parent tables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the switch from the database first approach to the code first approach. I wanted to be able to repopulate the database when it was dropped due to a POCO change. What I ended up doing was developing another small project to transfer data. The data transfer project has two EDMXs: One that points to a backup copy of the old database and another that points to the new database. I iterate over the entities in the backup DB and create new entities in the new DB. This is not the most elegant solution but it meets the needs for this project.

Answer (score 0):

In such case don't let EF to generate database and use only code mapping with existing database.

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(null);
```

Code first is for scenarios where you don't have database and you want EF to generate database for you.

Comment: I understand that there is the option to change the initializer. However, I want to be able to change my POCOs and repopulate the other table's data. That is why I asked the question. Sounds like you do not know of a way to do this.